# Не запускается webdriver.Chrome на vps с Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (ENG)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, selenium, chromedriver

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь запустить Chrome через webdriver на python. Версия Chrome 73 и chromedriver используется, соответствующий этой версии. Вылезает ошибка, которую не знаю как решить. Подскажите как поправить код.
Код программы:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = {}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(`start-maximized`)
options.add_argument(`disable-infobars`)
options.add_argument(`--disable-extensions`)
options.add_argument(`--disable-gpu`)
options.add_argument(`--disable-setuid-sandbox`)
options.add_argument(`--disable-dev-shm-usage`)
options.add_argument(`--no-sandbox`)
options.add_argument('--headless')
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=`/home/drivers/chromedriver`, options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get(`https://google.com`)
```

Ошибка (DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File `/home/parser/index.py`, line 131, in <module>
    configDriver(proxyData[0])
  File `/home/parser/index.py`, line 114, in configDriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=`/home/drivers/chromedriver`, options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py`, line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py`, line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py`, line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py`, line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py`, line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Linux 4.15.0-29-generic x86_64)
```

---

Замена `options=options` на `chrome_options=options` результата не дало, ошибка осталась. Есть еще варианты?

Comment: А если поправить `options=options` на `chrome_options=options`?

Comment: Я давно (года 3 назад) подключал Chrome, поэтому конечно же могу ошибаться, но!  1 - почему у вас опции (все кроме последней) ограничены Грависами, а не кавычками? 2 - почему одни опции добавляются без `--`, а другие с `--`? 3 - Пробовали ли вы запускать хром вообще без опций, с дефолтным профилем?

Comment: AtachiShadow,
1 - при вставке кода на stackoverflow я заменил символы кавычек не на те. В коде всё через одинарные кавычки.
2 - опции нашел также на stackoverflow, какие-то были с `--`, какие-то без. Добавил `--` ко всем опциям, но результат не изменился.
3 - если запустить без опций то будет та же ошибка: 
`(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вообщем причину ошибки я так и не нашёл, но решил её удалением chrome и установкой его заново.
Удаление:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Установка:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```